# Configure Logitech M705 on Ubuntu

Tags: mouse, logitech, configure

I have a Logitech M705 mouse and I'd like to configure the extra buttons on Ubuntu. I downloaded the xkeybinds, but I can't make it work. When only 1 key is binded, its fine, but I'd like to make a Ctrl+Page Up & Ctrl+Page Down key too, now that is what not working whatever I trying.

**I'd like to bind these buttons:**
Button 10: F5
Button 9: Ctrl+Page Down
Button 8: Ctrl+Page Up

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://rockingdlabs.dunmire.org/exercises-experiments/ubuntu-and-logitech-m705-buttons

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/190926/how-can-i-configure-a-logitech-m705-to-use-stepless-scrolling